# How do holograms work in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

So I’ve been catching back up on Star Wars the Clone Wars series. I’m on the last season, episode 8 to be exact. In one scene, we see Darth Maul communicating with the Pykes. Ahsoka sees Maul & he almost spots her. My question is, how can a hologram see the surroundings of a building? If they just can, why can we not see Maul’s surroundings? Is there any canonical reason or speculation?

Comment: The hologram is merely a projection from the hologram device. It's the device that's doing the sensing

Comment: Perhaps the same as you could see (or could not see) background on a video chat, i.e. depending on the camera view angle and other settings